# How to play video stream received from the network in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am streaming video(H264) across network on iOS.I am getting the data in buffers.Is there any way to play this streamed video on iOS? I cannot use AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController as these need the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a local "web server" and hand AVPlayer the URL to that? It's probably under 100 lines of code and pretty trivial to do with Apple's built-in classes. You'd then just hand out your buffers via the web server.